# Transform textarea input to paragraphed HTML

Tags: python, html, regex, newline, paragraph

I'd like to transform what the user inputs into an textarea on a html page into a `<p>`-tagged output where each `<p>` is replacing new lines.

I'm trying with regular expressions but I can't get it to work. Will someone correct my expression?

```
String = "Hey, this is paragraph 1 \n and this is paragraph 2 \n and this will be paragraph 3"
Regex = r'(.+?)$'
```

It just results in `Hey, this is paragraph 1 \n and this is paragraph 2 \n<p>and this will be paragraph 3</p>`

Comment: How are you using the regular expression?

Comment: Are you doing this for a website? Did you consider protection against [Cross-Site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)?

Comment: Just as a note, if you happen to be doing this within Django (unlikely, but possible), it has [a filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Django so that solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for this, simply because you do not need it. Check this out:

```
text = "Hey, this is paragraph 1 \n and this is paragraph 2 \n and this will be paragraph 3"
html = ''
for line in text.split('\n'):
   html += '<p>' + line + '</p>'

print html
```

To make it one line, because shorter is better, and clearer:

```
html = ''.join('<p>'+L+'</p>' for L in text.split('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
s = "Hey, this is paragraph 1 \n and this is paragraph 2 \n and this will be paragraph 3"
"".join("<p>{0}</p>".format(row) for row in s.split('\n'))
```

You basically split your string into a list of lines. Then wrap each line with paragraph tags. In the end just join your lines.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers relying on identifying '\n' do not work reliably. You need to use `.splitlines()`. I don't have enough rep to comment on the chosen answer, and when I edited the wiki, someone just reverted it. So can someone with more rep please fix it.

Text from a `textarea` may use '\r\n' as a new line character.

```
>> "1\r\n2".split('\n') 
['1\r', '2']
```

'\r' alone is invalid inside a webpage, so using any of the above solutions produce ill formed web pages.

Luckily python provides a function to solve this. The answer that works reliably is:

```
html = ''.join('<p>'+L+'</p>' for L in text.splitlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the anchor, `$`.  Your regex is trying to match *one or more of any non-newline characters, followed by the end of the string*.  You *could* use MULTILINE mode to make the anchors match at line boundaries, like so:

```
s1 = re.sub(r'(?m)^.+$', r'<p>\g<0></p>', s0)
```

...but this works just as well:

```
s1 = re.sub(r'.+', r'<p>\g<0></p>', s0)
```

The reluctant quantifier ( `.+?` ) wasn't doing anything useful either, but it didn't mess up the output like the anchor did.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy >>

```
html='<p>'+s.replace("\n",'</p><p>')+'</p>'
```